# Solidity-Contract in Vyper

Tags: solidity

```
contract myCoin {
        mapping (address => uint) coinBalanceOf;
        string coinName;
constructor(uint _supply, string memory _name) {
        coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] = _supply;
        coinName = _name;
}
function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount) {
                coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
                coinBalanceOf[receiver] += amount;
        }
}
function balance() public view returns (uint) { return coinBalanceOf[msg.sender]; }
function name() public view returns (string memory) { return coinName; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# @version 0.2.12

coinBalanceOf: HashMap[address, uint256]
coinName: String[32]

@external
def __init__(_supply: uint256, _name: String[32]):
    self.coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] = _supply
    self.coinName = _name

@external
def sendCoin(receiver: address, amount: uint256):
    if self.coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount:
        self.coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount
        self.coinBalanceOf[receiver] += amount

@external
@view
def balanceOf() -> uint256:
    return self.coinBalanceOf[msg.sender]

@external
@view
def name() -> String[32]:
    return self.coinName
```

1. You should use fixed-size String in Vyper.
2. You can't define `balance()` because it is already used for getting Eth balance in Vyper.